# How do I combine multiple bool method result to a single result using && and ||?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, operators

**sample:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool result =
        IsGreaterThanTen(1) &&
        IsGreaterThanTen(5) &&
        IsGreaterThanTen(10) ||
        IsGreaterThanTen(20);
}

static bool IsGreaterThanTen(int value)
{
    return value > 10;
}
```

I have to dynamically call the **IsGreaterThanTen** method many times
and combine them with **&&** or **||**, just like this sample

Maybe I have an array

```
int[] array = new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19.....};
```

and i will call **IsGreaterThanTen** method for each array item
and combine with **&&** or **||** to return a **bool** result.
it may looks like:

```
bool result = 
    IsGreaterThanTen(1) &&
    IsGreaterThanTen(3) ||
    IsGreaterThanTen(5) &&
    IsGreaterThanTen(7) ||
    IsGreaterThanTen(9) &&
    IsGreaterThanTen(11)..............
```

I can dynamic combine them with **&&** or **||** operator
and I just want to know the result
How to do this?

**Update:**
I want to combine them with `||` or `&&` according to an user setting.

Comment: Looks good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Is there some rule as to when to use `&&` or `||`?

Comment: They are Logical AND, Logical OR which do completely different things.

Comment: use && or || is according to user settings

Comment: what is this user setting a string or something? or am i not getting this question properly lol?

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};

var result = IsGreaterThanTen(array[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var number = array[i];
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        result = result && IsGreaterThanTen(number);
    }
    else
    {
        result = result || IsGreaterThanTen(number);
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: thanks, but I combine them with || or && is according to user setting

Comment: then you have to change `if (number % 2 == 0)` to something that checks which operator to use according to the setting...

Answer (score 2):

The question is still vague, but I think you are looking to get the && or the || for the whole set.  You can do that simply with a shortcutting loop.  (untested code, I don't have a C# runtime where I am)

```
bool testArray(int[] values, char op) {
    if ('&' == op) {
        for (int i = values.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (!IsGreaterThanTen(values[i])) {
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return true; // if none failed, then all passed
    } elseif ('|' == op) {
        for (int i = values.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (IsGreaterThanTen(values[i])) {
                 return true;
            }
        }
        return false; // if none passed, then all failed
    }
    return null; // an invalid op was passed
}

int[] array = new int[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19.....};
bool result = testArray(array, '&');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool result =
        (
        IsGreaterThanTen(1) &&
        IsGreaterThanTen(5)
        ) &&
        (
        IsGreaterThanTen(10) ||
        IsGreaterThanTen(20)
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way:

```
bool doIt(){
    if (IsGreaterThanTen(20))
        return true;
    else if  (!IsGreaterThanTen(1) 
        return false;
    else if(!IsGreaterThanTen(5))
        return false;
    else if(!IsGreaterThanTen(10))
        return false;
    else return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {     
    bool result = doIt();
}
```

In if statement it is important order of statements, 
so I put less expensive one in first

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea what the user setting is but you can try this:

```
var results = userSettings == "something1" ? IsGreaterThanTen(1) &&   
IsGreaterThanTen(3) ||   
IsGreaterThanTen(5) &&   
IsGreaterThanTen(7) ||   
IsGreaterThanTen(9) &&   
IsGreaterThanTen(11) : userSettings == "something2" ? IsGreaterThanTen(1) ||   
IsGreaterThanTen(3) &&
IsGreaterThanTen(5) ||
IsGreaterThanTen(7) &&   
IsGreaterThanTen(9) ||   
IsGreaterThanTen(11);
```

and so on, you can also combine this with the for loop if needed